# Find whether an Alternating Sequence is Convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum _{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{\left(\ln \left(n\right)\right)^k} \quad \text{ for } k>0$$

By Leibniz's test if $a_n \to 0$ for an alternating sequence it is convergent, over here if I take the value of $k\rightarrow 0$ and $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(a_n\right)$ then I would be able to say it is convergent. However, the limit appears to tend to $0$ when $k \to 0$ implying that the sequence is divergent. Am I right in this approach or am I doing something wrong while finding the limit. Is this series truly divergent?

Comment: $k$ is a fixed positive number. The question of letting $k \to 0$ does not arise.

Comment: On an **intuitive level** the *significance* of $~k~$ approaching $~0,~$ *from above* is that as $~k~$ decreases, one can **informally** say that the alternating series *takes longer* to converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence has a term $a_n = \frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{\left(\ln \left(n\right)\right)^k } \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$, decreases in absolute value, and the sequence is alternating, so its sum converges.

(The proof of this classical result is: as $a_n$ decreases in absolute value and has alternating sign, $\forall N, \forall k > N$, the sum from $2$ to $k$ is bounded by the sums from $2$ to $N$ and from $2$ to $N+1$, an interval whose length is $|a_{N+1}|$ which $\to 0$ when $N \to \infty$. So the sequence of sums to $N$ is a Cauchy sequence, in a compact set (bounded and complete), so it converges).

You are confused by the fact that there is a parameter $k$. But $k$ is fixed for a given sequence, so you do not have to think about what happens when $k \to 0$.

By the way, when talking about a sequence whose successive terms are summed, the convention is to call it a *series* rather than *sequence*.

Comment: For the alternating series criterion, it's important that $|a_n|$ *decreases* as well as converges to $0$ (consider a series whose terms alternate between $1/n$ and $-1/n^2$).

Comment: @ronno Yes, thanks for noting that I forgot this condition.